# AngularJS, TypeScript, RequireJS common base controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, requirejs, typescript

I am looking to create a common angular base controller with some custom methods, one of which allowing me to change the $scope of the controller (defaulting to $rootScope).  All other controllers can implement this base controller.  Can anyone provide any advanced examples or possibly some insight as to which direction I should take?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking to create a common angular base controller with some custom methods

All nested controllers inherit from the parent controllers. So this might be of use to you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24971239/390330

> can implement this base controller.

AngularJS favors composition over inheritance. If *you* do the controller inheritance (and not angular like in the previous example) *you* need to manage the `$inject` in each controller to pass any parameters to the parent e.g.

```
class Base{
 constructor(iNeedThisSevice){}
}
class Child extends Base{
 static $inject = ['iNeedThisService'];
 constructor(iNeedThisSevice){super(iNeedThisService);}
}
```